# If two objects are having same hashCode and qualify equality by equals, than why they fail for ==

Tags: java

Please follow the below code,

```
    String s1 = "ABC";
    String s2 = new String("ABC");
    String s3 = "ABC";

    System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); // 64578
    System.out.println(s2.hashCode()); // 64578     

    System.out.println(" s1 == s2 "+(s1 == s2)); //  s1 == s2 false
    System.out.println(" s1 == s3 "+(s1 == s3)); // s1 == s3 true
```

Here, both String s1 and s2 have same hashcode and qualify by equals, but fail equality by ==, why ?

Is it because s1 and s2 are different objects though both having the same hashcode and qalify by eqauls, if yes how come, please explain me ?

Also, please look at the below example,

```
class Employee{
private Integer employeeCode;

Employee(Integer empCode){
    this.employeeCode = empCode;    
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return this.employeeCode * 21;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    Employee emp = (Employee) o;

    return this.employeeCode.equals(emp.employeeCode);
}
} 

public class HashCodePractise01{


public static void main(String [] args){
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1);
    Employee e2 = new Employee(1);

    System.out.println(e1.hashCode()); // 21
    System.out.println(e2.hashCode()); // 21
    System.out.println("e1.equals(e2) "+(e1.equals(e2))); // e1.equals(e2) true 
    System.out.println("e1 == e2 "+(e1 == e2)); // e1 == e2 false
}
}
```

In the above example also, both employee objects have same hashcode and qualify equality by .equals method but still they fail equality in ==.

In both the above cases, why are they two different objects ? please explain

Comment: Because '==' checks if they are equal in terms of location in memory. They are different memory-wise but by implementing hashcode and equals you said you want them to be equal in a semantic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two Objects in Java will only ever evaluate to `==` if they share the same memory location (i.e. if they are literally the SAME object).

In your first example, `S1` and `S3` are equal because string are immutable, and, so, those literals can be smartly converted to a single cached string by java at compile-time (I think this happens at compile-time, could be runtime. I'm a bit fuzzy on java specifics, feel free to provide an edit if anyone knows for certain).

Answer (score 0):

For comparing 2 Strings, you have to use `.equals()` and not `==` because `.equals()` compare the value of Strings while `==` compare 2 objects(which will not be true anyhow).